# Redrawing gl2 isigraphs using event handler

Tags: j

I've been playing around with the table & gl2 demos, and have come across a "domain error: chkgl2" multiple times.

What I'm trying to do is to modify an isigraph after its initialized on program run, by selecting / un-selecting a checkbox.

I have the following code:

```
demo_run=: 3 : 0
require 'gl2'
coinsert 'jgl2'
wd 'pc test closeok escclose'
wd 'pn "Tester"'
wd 'cc gs isigraph'
wd 'cc cb checkbox; cn "Test GUI"'
wd 'set cb value 0'

wd 'pmove 400 10 400 200'
wd 'pshow'
)

demo_cb_button=: 3 : 0
demo_gs_paint''
)

demo_gs_paint=: 3 : 0
'w h'=: glqwh''
glfill 0 0 0 255
glrgb 255 223 0
glpen 2 1
if. cb do.
    for_i. 250*i. >. h%250 do.
         gllines 0,i,w,i
    end.
end.
)

demo_run''
```

What I'm expecting to happen is the checkbox to update the isigraph. What I'm getting is a "domain error: chkgl2" on line "glfill 0 0 0 255".

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that I spotted:

1) you are calling your parent `'test'` but you are giving the verbs a `'demo'` prefix. You can do this for the verb `demo_run`, but if you want the children of the form to react you will need to refer to them in the form of `test_cb_button`

2) `cb` in your test is actually the character '1' and not the integer 1, so in order for it to work as a conditional you need to change it to an integer type. I used Do (`".`) to make this change `(". cb)`

3) I am not sure that your code `250*i. >. h%250` is doing what you expect, so I replaced it with `i. >.h%15` and then changed the `gllines` command to `gllines 0,i,w,i*15` for a more interesting effect.

4) You are using `isigraph` which automatically triggers the painting of the screen and I wonder if the fact that you are clicking a button which triggers drawing of a screen to change the button image while also explicitly requiring the painting of the screen using the `test_gs_paint` verb is causing the `glfill` to be run twice. The second time it may be in a context that creates a domain error. To be honest, I don't know. What I do know is that when I use `isidraw` instead and trigger my own paint command using `glpaint ''` (which `isidraw` requires) that things seem to work.

5) I have added a second version that works with `isigraph` and it looks as if the issue is that by calling the paint verb directly with `test_gs_paint` that you were indeed calling it twice. By changing the action to `glpaint ''`, the form does rerun the painting of the entire form once and this causes `test_gs_paint` to update as well. This time though it does it in a more coordinated fashion. My second version reflects the change. Other corrections I have left in place.

My `isidraw` version of the code follows:

```
demo_run=: 3 : 0
require 'gl2'
coinsert 'jgl2'
wd 'pc test closeok escclose'
wd 'pn "Tester"'
wd 'cc gs isidraw' NB. changed from isigraph
wd 'cc cb checkbox; cn "Test GUI"'
wd 'set cb value 0'

wd 'pmove 400 10 400 200'
wd 'pshow'
)

test_cb_button=: 3 : 0
test_gs_paint''
)

test_gs_paint=: 3 : 0
'w h'=: glqwh''
glfill 0 0 0 255
glrgb 255 223 0
glpen 2 1
if. (".cb) do.  NB. needed to test on an integer and not a character value
    for_i. i. >.h%15 do.    NB. changed to give a more noticeable effect
         gllines 0,i,w,i*15
    end.
end.
glpaint'' NB. added to accommodate isidraw requirement of explicit painting
)

demo_run''
```

My `isigraph` version of the form:

```
demo_run=: 3 : 0
require 'gl2'
coinsert 'jgl2'
wd 'pc test closeok escclose'
wd 'pn "Tester"'
wd 'cc gs isigraph'
wd 'cc cb checkbox; cn "Test GUI"'
wd 'set cb value 0'

wd 'pmove 400 10 400 200'
wd 'pshow'
)

test_cb_button=: 3 : 0
glpaint ''  NB. changed from test_gs_paint ''
)

test_gs_paint=: 3 : 0
'w h'=: glqwh''
glfill 0 0 0 255
glrgb 255 223 0
glpen 2 1
if. (".cb) do.
    for_i. i. >.h%15 do.
         gllines 0,i,w,i*15
    end.
end.
)

demo_run''
```

Comment: Both versions work great. Thank you so much! The other comments were also very helpful.